# ArcMap line symbol with two different ends

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology

Is it possible to create a line symbol that has a round line end at the one end and a straight line end at the other using ArcMap?

[image: line]

I am only able to do something like this with arrow line symbols:

<----

---->

Comment: If you wish to ask the same question for ArcGIS Pro then please research/ask that as a separate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a "butt" style of [line cap](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/styles-and-symbols/essential-symbol-and-style-vocabulary.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_F17C49F7D3BF44AD9EC37699A05B89F5). This creates a flat end that stops exactly at the end of the line (as compared to "square" which extends the symbol past the geographic end of the line).

Add a [marker symbol layer](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/layer-properties/marker-symbol-layers.htm). Make the marker symbol a single black circle, the same width as the line, placed at the endpoint of the line.

Note: apparently this method works in ArcGIS Pro but not in ArcMap.

Comment: I can only add another line marker symbol layer not a point marker symbol layer.

Comment: Nice, I was able to do it in ArcGIS Pro but not in ArcMap. Thats why i asked for ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro in the same question. ;)

Comment: good to know. I added that info to my answer.